# C: How can I use the same char* [] multiple times without changing the values that already have been set to it?

Tags: c, structure

I have a while loop in my main function where the user is asked to input a string that is then passed on to a function that assigns it to some structure's textfield.

```
int main(void){
char text[255];
while(0) {
   scanf("%s", text);
   someFunction(text)
   }
}
someFunction(char* text){
someStruct str = malloc (sizeof (str));
str.textfield = text;
}
```

Now, I know that char arrays are passed by reference and so therefore all the created instances of someStruct will end up having the same textfield, namely the last one that was scanned and stored to "text". But how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Just assigning `text` to your structure field merely copies the pointer, so it will be overwritten with subsequent uses of `text`.  Instead, use `strdup(text)` to make a copy of the string (this just calls `malloc` and then copies the string into the newly allocated storage).

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the characters into your `malloc`ed string.  The simplest way to do it is to `strdup()` your string into your `textfield`:

```
str.textfield = strdup(text);
```

You would remove your `malloc()` if you did this.  `strdup()` does an implicit `malloc()`.